# Pulling data dynamically from MySQL using reactjs and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I have few doubts regarding dynamic updating few fields when an option is selected.

I am using PHP as backend, MySQL as DB and Reactjs for frontend. Below, when i change the value of test-instance then few parameters related to that test-instance must be dynamically pulled from mysql db and rendered on front end screen. I am confused as to how to proceed with this and the best way to handle these dynamic rendering from DB features when we use reactjs. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<FormField>
    <label>User Test Instance Name</label>
    <input id="testinstance" type ="text" value={this.state.testInst} onChange={this._onTestInstChange}/>
</FormField>

_onTestInstChange: function (event) {
        this.setState({testInst: event.target.value});
    },
    _onTestParam1Change: function (event) {
        this.setState({testParam1: event.target.value});
    },
    _onTestParam2Change: function (event) {
        this.setState({testParam2: event.target.value});
    },
    _onTestParam3Change: function (event) {
        this.setState({testParam3: event.target.value});
},
```

Comment: are you trying to change the value of an html object like <p> or <span>? everything looks setup correctly you just aren't doing anything with the update functions